# Count the digits in a number

Tags: python, filter, count

I have written a function called `count_digit`:

```
# Write a function which takes a number as an input
# It should count the number of digits in the number
# And check if the number is a 1 or 2-digit number then return True 
# Return False for any other case
def count_digit(num):
    if (num/10 == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + count_digit(num / 10);


print(count_digit(23))
```

I get `325` as output. Why is that and how do I correct it?

Comment: Using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: `return len(str(num))`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama, OP might be trying to do a recursive function. This works tho

Comment: You should use integer division (`//` instead of `/`) or the simpler method suggested here.

Comment: What exactly is meant by _number of digits in the number_?

Comment: for ex. 1982 has 4 digits in it @Timus

Comment: How many digits has 111111111?

Comment: @MichaelButscher But why wouldn't single \ work??? and double work???

Comment: Single slash  is float division, therefore e. g. `7/10` is about `0.7` (not even exactly) while `7//10 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `Python3` behaviour. `/` returns `float` and not `integer` division.

Change your code to:

```
def count_digit(num):
    if (num//10 == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + count_digit(num // 10)

print(count_digit(23))
```

Comment: how about removing the 'else', it's after return

Comment: @datdinhquoc I think that for beginners it is better to explicitly have an "else" here.

Answer (score 1):

convert the integer to a string, and then use the len() method on the converted string. Unless you also consider taking floats as input too, and not integers exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

## Recursive

```
def count_digit(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return count_digit(n // 10) + 1
```

## Easy

```
def count_digit(n):
    return len(str(abs(n)))
```

Comment: @Timus done. Added `abs()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always send integer to function and you are asking for a mathematical answer, this might be your solution:

```py
import math


def count_digits(number):
    return int(math.log10(abs(number))) + 1 if number else 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_digits(15712))
    # prints: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy solution in python;

```
num=23
temp=num #make a copy of integer
count=0

#This while loop will run unless temp is not zero.,so we need to do something to make this temp ==0

while(temp): 
  temp=temp//10  # "//10" this floor division by 10,remove last digit of the number.,means we are removing last digit and assigning back to the number;unless we make the number 0
  count+=1 #after removing last digit from the number;we are counting it;until the number becomes Zero and while loop becomes False
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

What Greg_Kan suggests:

```
len(str(num))
```